How can I correctly render an OWL component using t-component in an Odoo view template? Am I missing something in the setup or registration?
I am trying to render an OWL component in Odoo using t-component within my view template. However, the component is not loading, and nothing appears on the page.
Here's what I've done:
1.My OWL Component:
/** @odoo-module **/

import { Component } from "@odoo/owl";

export class ProductImageGallery extends Component {
    setup() {
        console.log("ProductImageGallery component is working");
    }
}
ProductImageGallery.template = "multi_image_master.ProductImageGalleryTemplate";


2.My Component Template:
<template id="ProductImageGalleryTemplate" name="Product Image Gallery">
    <div>
        <h3>Product Image Gallery</h3>
        <p>Gallery of images for this product will appear here.</p>
    </div>
</template>

views/xml file
This is supposed to render the component using t-component:
<template id="ProductPageTemplate" name="Product Page">
    <t t-call="website.layout">
        <div id="product-page-content" class="container">
            <t t-component="multi_image_master.ProductImageGallery"/>
            <p>Hello Bharathi</p>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>

Controller:
The page is loaded via this controller.
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request

class ControllerProductPage(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/shop', type='http', auth='public', website=True, csrf=False)
    def renderProductPage(self, **kwargs):
        return request.render('multi_image_master.ProductPageTemplate', {})

manifest file
   {
    "name": "Product Multi-Image Manager",
    "version": "0.1",
    "category": "Product",
    "depends": ["website"],
    "data": [
        "views/product_template.xml"
    ],
    "assets": {
        "web.assets_backend": [
            "multi_image_master/static/src/js/product_image_gallery.js",
            "multi_image_master/static/src/xml/product_image_gallery.xml"
        ]
    },
    "installable": True,
    "application": True,
    "license": "LGPL-3"
}


Issue:
When I load the /shop route, the page renders the static content but does not render the component (t-component="multi_image_master.ProductImageGallery"). Also, the console.log() in the setup method of the component does not execute, indicating that the component is not being loaded.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

question is same but Answer is not found
